# IOS Vars on AppDelegate are released when app enter in background?

Tags: ios, memory-management, appdelegate

This is a question about iOS memory management when app enters the background.
If I have a var in the `AppDelegate` with a value:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject  {
    NSString *userName;
}

// In some place
((MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).userName = @"StackOverflow"
```

My question is: when the app enters the background, because the user receives a call or opens another app, is it possible that iOS releases the memory for any reason (so destroying my `AppDelegate` instance)? So I lose the value of `userName`?

Programming in Android we have to use persistence mechanisms like `Parcelable`, using methods of lifecycle like `onSaveInstance`, etc. But in iOS we don't have to manage values of var for the "iOS garbage collection"?

Maybe the answer can be trivial talking about a `String` var, but what happens when I stored in the `AppDelegate` a big `Array` of `UIImage`s? It will never be release when app enter on background?

Sorry for my bad english and I can't find information about lifecycle iOS, appDelegate and memory management.

Comment: Try it, see what happens.

Comment: Under normal circumstances it shouldn't release your vars. what might happen, is if the memory is needed, that your app gets killed due to iOS needing memory.

Comment: These vars are not released when app goes "normally" to the backgorund: user presses the home button or receives a call... but they might be released (as well as the app itself) whilst your app is in background. Many (many!) users have a tendency to clean (close) the background-running apps frome time to time (with double-tapping home and swiping apps off & out...). So make sure to save important data either when this data changes or when your app enters background.

Answer (score 1):

You never really know. iOS might need to remove the app from memory to use it for something else. If the user closes the app for just a minute then you might be ok, but the app could be closed for days, and the user may do any number of other things...

So, you should really either:

1. Save data each time it changes, or
2. Save data when the app is told that it is going to the background

Option 1. is more safe, because it also saves data against crashes, but it isn't always practical. Generally, save as soon as you can and, if testing shows you need to, later work on making things run better (like by processing and saving to disk on a background thread).

Answer (score 0):

When an app is launched, the UIApplicationMain function is called, this function creates a singleton `UIApplication` object.

When you declare an iVar like this : `NSString *userName;` you are creating a `strong` reference to it ( by default it's `strong`).

To answer your question : the `userName` will be released when the `UIApplication` will be released and because the `UIApplication` is a singleton, it will be never release until the application is not killed. The application will be killed in many situations :

1. The user kill the app
2. The system kill the app (memory,...)

Documentation :

[Memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

[iOS App life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24)